# Python if is boolean statements

Tags: python, if-statement, pycharm

I am having a problem in a simple expression which is the following.

```
number=int(input("enter the number"))
for n in range(40-101):
    if n % number is 0:
        print(n)
```

When I enter 10 as an input it prints nothing as an output. With my elementary school math, I can easily assume that this should print all the numbers which can be divided by 10.

So the problem should be in the `if` statement. It doesn't enter to `print(n)`.

I am using PyCharm Community Edition and Python 3.4

Comment: _"since they use "is" in everywhere..."_ Who is "they"? I suggest you stop listening to them because you should barely ever use `is`.

Comment: The only common occurrence of `is` I can think of off the top of my head is when you're checking `if something is None`, and that's only because it's semantically more correct. `something == None` still works - it's just not as nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should use `==` instead of `is` in this case because:

   > `is` checks if two object's `id` are the same, and `==` checks if two object's values are the same.
2. Well, `range(40-101)` gives `range(-61)` and that's treated as `range(0, -61)`. Let's see:

   ```
   >>> range(40-101)
   range(0, -61)
   >>> list(range(40-101))
   []
   ```

   I think you mean `range(40, 101)` right?

So your code should look like:

```
number = int(input("Enter the number: "))
for n in range(40, 101):
    if n % number == 0:
        print(n)
```

Demo:

```
Enter the number: 10
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

---

Just got an idea to improve your code, you don't need `%` in this case since [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) has a `step` argument. From the document:

> `class range(stop)`
>   `class range(start, stop[, step])`
>
> The arguments to the range constructor must be integers (either built-in int or any object that implements the `__index__` special method).
>
> If the `step` argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. If step is zero, `ValueError` is raised.
>
> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.

So as the document says, you can also set the `step` instead of use `%` to check *all the numbers which can be divided by `number`* manually use `if`. For example:

```
number = int(input("Enter the number: "))
for n in range(40, 101, number):
    print(n)
```

Comment: This is true but after the suggestion of Arc676, I tried to execute my same code in range(40,101,1) with number as 10.It works.So I thik is works for integers but fails for strings etc just like java.So what I mean is two different strings with same content are false according to is.But two different variables with same integer values are equal according to is

Comment: The third argument of [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) is `step`. So however, there's no difference between `range(40,101,1)` and `range(40,101)`. But huh, I have a good idea to improve your code.

Comment: @Juwan: And however, I don't see any string in your code, you already converted the input string to integer use `int()` function right?

Comment: Yes, I think it works like that.Because if you try to enter someting like name as an input code fails since it cannot parse it to an integer value.

Comment: @Juwan: Oh, you mean that. Then you can use `try...except` to catch the `ValueError` which `int()` raised. I think you'll learn that soon ;)

Comment: @Juwan: And I've edited my answer: Quoted the document and suggested a better way to do this.